# Problem writing int to binary file in C

Tags: c, file, binary, int

I need to write data to a binary file using C's I/O functions. The following code causes a runtime exception :

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("path_to_file.bin","wb");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("error creating file");
        return -1;
    }
    int val = 4;
    fwrite((const void*)val,sizeof(int),1,fp);
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

The code dies at the fwrite. Can you spot what I'm doing wrong? Apparently, I'm, trying to access data at 0x0000004 or something like that.

Thanks !

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
 fwrite((const void*)val,sizeof(int),1,fp);
```

should be:

```
 fwrite((const void*) & val,sizeof(int),1,fp);
```

BTW, if you don't use the cast, you will get a sensible error message. Casts tend to be used by C (and C++) programmers far more often than they should be - a good rule of thumb  is "if it needs a cast, it's probably wrong".

Comment: + another 1 for that rule.  i have it on a sticky note on my monitor.

Answer (score 27):

I think Neil's answer can be improved upon. I realize it's already accepted, so this is just to show some contrast (which is why I didn't just edit his).

```
fwrite(&val, sizeof val, 1, fp);
```

Two improvements:

- No pointer casting, since it's not necessary in C and can hide errors.
- Use `sizeof` directly on the object, since that is what you're passing a pointer to. Makes a lot of sense to me, and is safer than repeating yourself and using the type name.

Comment: +1 Good points, both. Moral of the story: prefer as little casts and use sizeof judiciously.

Comment: Can you please explain why the cast isn't necessary? I'm not a C programmer ... and I would like to understand as much as possible of it's "magic".

Comment: fwrite() expects a void* as its first argument. Any pointer type can be used where a void* is expected without casting. void* effectively says "I need a pointer, I don't care what type it points to".

Comment: Not required in C. Especially with pointers. You can assign a pointer to void to a pointer to any object type and vice versa

Answer (score 5):

Adding to Neil's answer: this works when you are reading and writing the file on the same platform. Things can become weird if you are reading/writing across platforms with different endianness.

Comment: Not only endianness, also the size may vary.

Comment: C is soo not multi platform, in the file writing/reading you need to make a implementation for each platform most times, different end of line markers and things like that become a nightmare when dealing with file writing/reading across platforms (kindda off topic anyway :P)

Answer (score 0):

```
#include "stdio.h"

int main(int argc,char* argv[]) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("path_to_file.bin","wb");
    if(fp == NULL) {
        printf("error creating file");
        return -1;
    }
    int val = 4;
    fwrite((const void*)val,sizeof(int),1,fp);
```

You should supply an address not integer itself.

Additionaly you should not use the integer in such way:

1. It may differ in endianess on different computers (as mentioned)
2. It may differ in size. On really old computers it may be 1 or 2 bytes. On most modern it will be 4 but it *may* be 8 as well (some 64-bit computers). On some strange architectures it may be even 36 bits. `int32_t val = 4; fwrite((const void *)val, 4, 1, fp)` should solve the problem.

You may think that your software will never need to be ported. Well - many designers (software and hardware) made similar assumptions. Sometimes it is too costly to not make them - but in this case it is just a matter of few additional checks.

```
    fclose(fp);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this kind of problem. So this is my solution.

`fwrite(val, sizeof(val[0], sizeof(val)/sizeof(val[0]), fp);`

Answer (score 0):

> Apparently, I'm, trying to access data at 0x0000004 or something like that.

```
int val = 4
```

There's the issue. `fwrite` is designed to work with strings, and as such its first input is a pointer, the location of a string in memory. You are passing the value of `val` directly (4) rather than the address of `val` to `fwrite`; however, the memory at 0x00000004 is not valid program memory and thus an error is given.

To fix this, change this:

```
fwrite((const void*)val,sizeof(int),1,fp);
```

Into this:

```
fwrite((const void*)&val, sizeof(int), 1, fp);
```

The "&" operator indicates the location of `val`. This would be a valid address in memory.